# TemplateDoesNotExit error when deploying project on heroku

Tags: django, templates, heroku

I am trying to deploy my project on heroku but I am stumbling on the above error. Everything works fine when i run the code locally. Below are my setting and views file

template settings

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

views of my Home app

```
def Home(request):
    return render(request,'Home/index.html')
```

Comment: Is this working good on Local Host ?

Comment: Make sure to define the version of Django in your `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile`. You might be running a version locally different from the one getting installed when deploying to Heroku.
Try to run your local server with `heroku local` instead of `python manage.py run server` and see if it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this ( In settings.py ) :-

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: This is  the previous setting, it was giving me the same error so i edited it thinking it would solve the problem. When i run the code locally everything works fine, i dont know why heroku cant find my templates @peter

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion. I solved the error by renaming my templates from 'index.html' to 'main.html'